# Spark code is taking a long time to return query. Help on speeding this up

Tags: apache-spark, hive, beeline

I am currently running some Spark code and I need to query a data frame that is taking a long time (over 1 hour) per query. I need to query multiple times to check if the data frame is in fact correct.

I am relatively new to Spark and I understand that Spark uses lazy evaluation which means that the commands are executed only once I do a call for some action (in my case **.show()**).

Is there a way to do this process once for the whole DF and then quickly call on the data?

Currently I am saving the DF as a temporary table and then running queries in beeline (HIVE). This seems a little bit overkill as I have to save the table in a database first, which seems like a waste of time.

I have looked into the following functions `.persist`, `.collect` but I am confused on how to use them and query from them.

I would really like to learn the correct way of doing this.

Many thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: Please post some code in order to help us troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep your **RDD in memory** using `rddName.cache()` (or `persists()`) . More information about **RDD Persistence** can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am currently running:
`myDF.cache()`
`myDF.filter().show()`

is this the correct use? It has been running for around 10 mins which feels a little slow.

Comment: When you `cache` an `RDD`, this is going to be keep in memory for further use in the very same program. If you are running a scala shell, doing the `cache()` will keep this in memory (after the `show()`), so next queries over this DataFrame should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary table ( registerTempTable (spark 1.6) or createOrReplaceTempView (spark2.x)) does not "save" any data. It only creates a view with the lifetime of you spark session. If you wish to save the table, you should use `.saveAsTable`, but I assume that this is not what you are looking for.

Using `.cache` is equivalent to `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY)`. If your table is large and thus can't fit in memory, you should use `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`.

Also it is possible that you simple need more nodes in you cluster. In case you are running locally, make sure you deploy with `--master local[*]` to use all available cores on your machine. If you are running on a stand alone cluster or with a cluster manager like Yarn or Mesos, you should make sure that all necessary/available resources are assigned to you job.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I understand better now.

Comment: you are welcome, @CapitalPhi. If you supply more details, I will probably be able to help even more.
Spark can have a rather steep learning curve, but once you pass the first hill, it gets better.